# tkinter file open dialog with pattern

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using `tkinter`'s `tkFileDialog` to get file open dialog box. I want `.txt` files starting with `24`. Here is the code

```
options = {}
options['filetypes'] = [('RMS Files', '24*.txt')]
options['title'] = 'Please select file'
file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**options)
```

The code works well in UBUNTU. But in WINDOWS it prepends a `*` to the pattern ie the pattern becomes `RMS files (*24*.txt)` so some unwanted files are also shown. How can i solve this?